# Adding conditions in web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, web-applications, web.xml

This is a part of my web.xml

```
    <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/index</location>
    </error-page>
```

Is there any way to tell  to web.xml file  that in development mode :

`<location>/displayException</location>`

for the above  `location property` ?

or any way to add condition through code ?

**Purpose of trying to do this  is:** In development mode I want to see the exception in page and in live mode I want to redirect him to default page when an exception occured.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it in `web.xml` level. This could be a cool feature if `web.xml` respect system properties but it does not.

So you only way is to do this in code. Fortunately you have various possibilities. You can map your error URL to JSP where you implement logic based on system property or other parameter stored in property file, DB or where you want. You can do it in HTTP filter as well.

You can also create several versions of your web.xml: one for production, other for tests. If you want to avoid duplications create these versions using automatic generation from template.

Comment: **several versions of your web.xml** will do this.Because there are serveral changes like this.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Wildfly there is a non-portable way to enable system properties evaluation in web.xml (and others, like persistence.xml). To do this specify the following in your server configuration (standalone.xml or other), in the `ee` subsystem:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:2.0">
    <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>true</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
    <!-- ... -->
</subsystem>
```

Then you could do things like this:

```
<location>${myapp.errorpage.location}</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if statements in error or location page. `web.xml` doesn't support if statements.

```
//error page
if("blog".equals(url))
    blog content ......
else if("profile".equals(url))
    profile content ......
```

Comment: // error page
 if("blog".equals(url))
blog content ......
else if("profile".equals(url))
profile content ......